# Use FormHelper in Twig template

Tags: cakephp, twig

i'm working on a class project with cakePhp Framework and i migrated from ctp views to twig views, however i have a probleme in rendring a login form to a 'login.twig' view i dont know how to show it.

the login.ctp file was this:

```
<div class="users form">

<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?= __("Merci de rentrer vos nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe")          ?></legend>
    <?= $this->Form->input('username') ?>
    <?= $this->Form->input('password') ?>
  </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Se Connecter')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

How can i do the same thing with twig ?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you working with ?

Comment: as I understand you should write `{{ $this->Form->create() }}` instead of `<?= $this->Form->create() ?>` in your twig templates